# get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

started getting this error after I updated Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient from version 2.05 to 3.05.

Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault, Version=3.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation

Any idea how I can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to confirm your `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault` dependencies version.

> At the time 3.0.5 was built, we depended on `Newtonsoft.Json` `10.0.3`. Do you have that or newer installed into your project? If you do, another possibility is something another team hit: a version of Json .NET was in the GAC but specific for net35, which is lacking some types that were necessary. If you can, check that you're not picking up a GAC's copy of Json .NET.

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/8831#issuecomment-555732508).

[image]

Comment: I'm running in an Azure function and am also facing this issue. Due to how the nature of azure functions we have to using binding redirects (https://www.thewissen.io/azure-functions-binding-redirects/). I have tried binding different newtonsoft.json versions (10.3, 11, 12) but still get this error. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: You can create a case to post your situation with more details, so we can help you more professionally.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem too, it seems that Azure Functions v1 (this old version is required as it's some legacy .NET Framework code) is locked to Newtonsoft 9.0, whereas Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault requires Newtonsoft 10+

This is not reconcilable, so it seems to be impossible to use the Key Vault SDK inside an Azure Function V1.

**However**, the Azure SDK v4 is now out, and doesn't have a Newtonsoft dependency. So a workaround is to use the v4 SDK instead, which doesn't give this error does appear to work inside an Azure Function.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer on the Key Vault SDK, I recommend upgrading to Azure.Security.KeyVault.*. Not only do they not take a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json, they have better logging, faster performance, less memory overhead, and the pipeline is more extensible. Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault* will only get critical fixes, and some new features for Key Vault are already in preview so moving to v4 (same as Azure.Security.KeyVault.*) would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault` down to version `3.0.3`
Dependency for that version: `Newtonsoft.Json (>= 6.0.8)` for `.NetFramework 4.5.2`

Azure Functions V1 use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.24`
Dependency for that version: `Newtonsoft.Json (= 9.0.1)` for `.NetFramework 4.6`

So it is possible to use Azure KeyVault stuff for Azure Functions V1.
It is needed to make a little bit tunning used versions of additional packages.
Maybe it is not the best way, but it is the simplest way. And it works!